# How to create geotif from given csv file

Tags: geospatial, geotiff, rasterizing

I am trying to convert a csv file into geotiff. My .csv file contains polygon coordinates in 1 column and value in another column. e.g.-

```
id,polygon,val
1,[(2.43534,23.353453),(2.13534,22.353453),(2.53534,22.053453),...],12.15
2,[(12.43534,23.353453),(12.13534,22.353453),(12.53534,22.053453),...],16.15
...
```

The approach I tried is - I created a shapefile for each polygon(each row) and trying to combine all the shapefiles into a raster - Is it possible?

Also Please suggest any other approach to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your polygons don't overlap you should be able to make one shapefile containing all the polygons and then use [`gdal_rasterize`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html) to rasterize the shapefile into a raster.

something like:

```
gdal_rasterize -a val -ts 1000 1000 -l shape shape.shp raster.tif
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I created the shapefile for all polygons as suggested. But now I am getting error while rasterizing the shapefile.  


gdal_rasterize -a val -l shape testpysh/testpysh.shp raster.tif


ERROR 1: Attempt to create -2147483648x-2147483648 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.
ERROR 1: Cannot create raster.tif

Comment: gdal_rasterize -a val -l shape testpysh/testpysh.shp raster.tif should be something like gdal_rasterize -a val -l testpysh testpysh/testpysh.shp raster.tif - the -l is the layer name, use ogrinfo to find out what it should be

Comment: Hi Ian,
INFO: Open of `testpysh/testpysh.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: testpysh
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2019-03-22
Geometry: 3D Polygon
Feature Count: 345
Extent: (-16.225000, -5.600000) - (54.083336, 42.004169)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS_84",63..,298.25..]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
SUBID: Real (24.15)


gdal_rasterize

ERROR 1: Attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero

Comment: it seems that if the tiff doesn't exist you must specify what size you want with -ts option

Comment: Thanks Ian,

Now the rasterize worked properly, But the output tiff file is very small(1 kb), Only  some pixels got plotted. Whereas I have around 10000 polygons in my shapefile(100mb size).

When I increase the -ts / -tr tif size increases but it creates a blank tiff

Am I missing something? Please suggest